# Python dictionary assignment by substring

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

Given a pre-existing Python dictionary:

```
my_dict = {
    "Robert" : 37,
    "Kevin"  : 25,
    "Mark"   : 81,
}
```

What would be the most efficient way of inserting a new value for an existing key in this structure, if you were only provided a sub-string or a different-case version of the key? E.g. "Rob" or "kev"

What I have presently works, but I'm doing something like the following, which is O(N^2) for multiple inputs:

```
for key in list(my_dict):
    if my_input.name.lower() in key.lower():
        my_dict[key] = my_input.value
        break
```

Comment: Why do `for key in list(my_dict):` instead of simply `for key in my_dict:`? Also you don't have to call `my_input.lower()` in each iteration. Just do it once before the loop.

Comment: @pault Yeah, fair points. My actual code is a bit different, I just threw that up as an example of what I was doing. Also, absolutely no idea why I wrote "list(my_dict)".

Comment: If this is the case, a dictionary here is useless, incurring unnecessary overhead. Use a list of tuples instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as I explained in the comments under the question, there are a few things you can do to optimize your existing code:

```
my_dict = {
    "Robert" : 37,
    "Kevin"  : 25,
    "Mark"   : 81,
    "Andre"  : 55
}

# optimized version of existing code
def update_key(my_dict, my_input, my_value):
    my_input = my_input.lower()
    for key in my_dict:
        if my_input in key.lower():
            my_dict[key] = my_value
            break
```

As [@Stephen Rauch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48738732/5858851) did, I think building an index is the way to go. However, I think that building every possible substring of each key is costly. Furthermore, it's not robust to substrings that occur at the middle or the end of the string.

Here is an alternative index-based approach. The idea is that we concatenate all the keys together and build one string. We also keep track of the length of each string in a list.

Then for a given test string, we use `str.find()` (which should be `O(N)`) to find the index of the substring. Next we count off in the length array to find the corresponding key.

```
def create_index(my_dict):
    key_str = ""
    key_lengths = []
    for key in my_dict:
        key_str += key
        key_lengths.append(len(key))

    # return the concatenated keys, a lower case version, and the lengths list
    return (key_str, key_str.lower(), key_lengths)

def key_lookup(key_str, key_str_lower, key_lengths, my_input):
    idx = key_str_lower.find(my_input.lower())
    if idx == -1:
        return None
    len_sum = 0
    for kl in key_lengths:
        if idx < len_sum+kl:
            return key_str[len_sum:len_sum+kl]
        else:
            len_sum += kl
    return None

key_str, key_str_lower, key_lengths = create_index(my_dict)

print key_str_lower
#andrerobertkevinmark
print key_lengths
#[5, 6, 5, 4]
```

Example output:

```
print(key_lookup(key_str, key_str_lower, key_lengths, my_input='rob'))
#Robert
print(key_lookup(key_str, key_str_lower, key_lengths, my_input='dre'))
#Andre
```

#### Notes

- I think your existing code might be better than this solution. It is definitely more readable, and easier to understand.
- There are ways to modify this as well, depending on your actual purpose. For instance, instead of looping through and calculating the string offsets you could store each possible offset in a dictionary in the form of `{offset: key}`. This increases the index creation time slightly and uses more space, but the lookups would be faster.
- As in the original example, this will return the first match in the case where the substring is contained in multiple strings. Since dictionaries are unordered, one may choose to sort the keys when building the index so that the output is deterministic.

---

#### Timing Results

```
import random
import string

random.seed(12345)

N = 1000
my_dict = {
    ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(random.randint(3,30))): j for j in range(N)
}

def key_lookup_orig(my_dict, my_input):
    my_input = my_input.lower()
    for key in my_dict:
        if my_input in key.lower():
            return key
    return None

subs = [k[random.randint(0,len(k)-1):max(random.randint(0,len(k)), len(k))] for k in my_dict]

%%timeit
sum([1 if not key_lookup_orig(my_dict, s) else 0 for s in subs])
#1000 loops, best of 3: 1.5 ms per loop

key_str, key_str_lower, key_lengths = create_index(my_dict)

%%timeit
sum([1 if not key_lookup(key_str, key_str_lower, key_lengths, my_input=s) else 0 for s in subs])
#1000 loops, best of 3: 795 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it is the *most* effcient way, but you can build a index into the data using a `dict` like:

#### Build Index:

```
def build_index(data):
    lookup = {}
    for k in data:
        orig = k
        k = k.lower()
        while k:
            if k in lookup:
                lookup[k] = None
                break
            lookup[k] = orig
            k = k[:-1]
    return lookup
```

#### Use Index:

```
def findit(value, lookup, data):
    k = lookup.get(value.lower())
    if k is not None:
        return data[k]
```

#### Test Code:

```
data = {
    "Robert": 37,
    "Kevin": 25,
    "Mark": 81,
}

lookup = build_index(data)
print(findit('kev', lookup, data))
print(findit('Rob', lookup, data))
```

#### Results:

```
25
37
```

Comment: Building the index could be very costly upfront, especially if the keys are long. Plus what if the key is "Andre" and the substring is "dre"? This wouldn't work in that case.

Comment: @pault, Very True. This is the great thing about optimization.  The answer is often: it depends...  weighing the index build time against the lookup speedup, is gonna have to be the user's responsibility

Comment: Ok so we can assume that the substring are always at the beginning of the word? Meaning the example I showed won't happen?

Comment: The substring may or may not include the beginning of the word. I may edit the question itself, but what's populating the dict is OCR. I read a label with a camera, push the image to GCP's Cloud Vision API, and get a JSON back. The problem is, from testing, it sometimes misses characters on word boundaries, or will read "K" as "k". Just re-read your other comment, I misunderstood it at first, yeah the 'dre' / 'Andre' instance could be a problem

Answer (score 1):

So you are talking about equivalence class where the equivalence relation may be substring, or case-insensitive equality, and you map elements in the same equivalence class to the same value. Unless there is a way to consistently convert elements of the same equivalence class to a unique representative, a dictionary here is useless, and only incurs unnecessary overhead. If this is the case, use a simpler data structure, like list of tuples instead. Every time you need to do an update, you iterate through the whole list, doing an equivalence test for each element.

That said, your best bet is to figure out an efficient algorithm to convert elements to its equivalence representative, and then use dictionary. This is like use hash table only if you can figure out an efficient hash function for your scenario.